# US visa from Bangkok, Thailand and wish to visit another country

Tags: visas, usa, thailand

I live in Thailand and hold a B1/B2 visa to the US. If I wish to visit Canada or some other place can i enter Canada or other place with my B1.B2 US visa?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Why would you assume that a US visa would allow you to enter another country?  You may be allowed to transit without a visa with a US visa but that's about it.

Comment: Canada is not a European country. Not that it's relevant, since I don't any countries that will let you in with a visa for the US, but can you edit so that the body and title don't contradict each other?

Comment: @Karlson Sometimes that is the case. B1-B2 visa holders are allowed to visit Mexico border towns, for instance, without any further visas.

Answer (score 2):

Your U.S. visa will not let you visit Canada or any European countries. The only countries I know besides the U.S. that it will allow you to visit are Mexico and Costa Rica. (Possibly some Caribbean countries too, not sure.)